# UWP C# How to Write to Event Log

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, event-log

I am trying to add an EventLog to my UWP app, but I was not able to reference it in System.Diagnostic. After doing some research, I'm starting to think that it is not apart of UWP's API. I have found alternatives to writing an EventLog using both FileLoggingSession and LoggingSesssion, but was wondering if there is a way to write to a windows EventLog? If not, is there an Open Source or NuGet package that will do this for me?

Answer (score -1):

The sandboxed nature of UWP apps means you don't have direct access to the event log.  There are a number of ways around it, but they are not valid in a store-deployed scenario.

Comment: The app is doing an in-house deployment, so what are those ways around it?

Answer (score -2):

You can write the `Action<string>` in a static class and write

```
public Action<string> reminder;
```

Reminder: add the code that writes the file in the Local Folder, and you can see the file that you write.

And I write the error in catch(Expetion e) and write `reminder=e.Message;`

But it cannot see it running.